# Term for 3D Surface Mapped into 2D Plane

Tags: terminology, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, isometry

Is there a mathematical term (or field of study) related to mapping surface in 3D into 2D planes without bending or stretching? To give an example, the exterior of a cone can be covered in a wrapper that has the shape of a circular sector. Or a cylinder can be “unwound” into a simple rectangle. Is there a word for this type of mapping like “deformation” or something along those lines?

Comment: A "[developable surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Developable_surface)" [can](http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node190.html) be mapped [isometrically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry) to a plane. But I don't know if there's a better word/phrase than "flatten". This is not an answer because I don't work with differential geometry and don't know if they have a better word to use, but it might help you find an answer that satisfies you.

Comment: Well, for instance, a longitude line plotted on a transverse mercator map projection does not follow a North grid line when the longitude line is offset from zone center. The angular difference between the longitude line and the North grid line is convergence at any point of the projection. The longitude line would seem to be flattened but not straightened.